# System.UnauthorizedAccess Exception C#

Tags: c#, exception, unauthorized

I currently have a compiled C# program but whenever I run it I get the Windows encountered a problem error.

This is from a System.UnauthorizedAccess error, how can I give access and remove this error without any need from the user side, since this program is being deployed to a lot of people and I don't want them having to make this fix manually.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more information, please? Do you have the text of the exception, or the line of code that's causing it?

Comment: I think we would need to know what your application is doing, to be able to find a solution. But if the other answers are what your looking for in this case, UAC would be your problem, and writing to a more accessible folder is your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current user's application data folder using the environment variable APPDATA.  Therefore, you can do something like:

```
string appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
string configFile = Path.Combine(appdata, configFile);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(configFile);
writer.WriteLine("my config data");
writer.Close();
```

You can also use this approach to get the temporary folder as well.  You can even generate a random file name using the BCL functions.  I think it's `Path.GetTempFilename()`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application ask for Administrator's privileges at any time?

Comment: Yes it does ask for admin privileges, a lot of my users found that it happened when opening the application. And if the application doesn't find the config file on start then it creates it therefore it may be having problems creating this in the program files environment.

Comment: Well there's your problem. Under UAC you cannot create files in Program Files without elevating. Nor should you be doing it there anyway, there are better places to keep global settings.

Comment: O ok then, How would I put the config file somewhere decent like in appdata?